# Kinect with arm_navigation

Tags: navigation, mapping, kinect, collision, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have any sample code for adding a kinect sensor to the arm_navigation code that is generated by the planning_environment wizard in Electric?  I had it working in diamondback but I am having problems getting the collision map to show up.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10917/kinect-with-arm_navigation/) by [Jake](https://answers.ros.org/users/721/jake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forgot, you might also want to look at collider:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/collider

In fact, collider might do exactly what you're asking.

---

Originally posted by [Matt Klingensmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/942/matt-klingensmith/) with karma: 141 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arm navigation wizard uses the new environment server code released with electric. This tutorial explains in detail how the environment server works:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Understanding%20the%20Planning%20Scene%20architecture

Basically, what you'll eventually want to do is generate a collision map from your kinect point cloud, and then publish a new planning scene containing the collision map to the environment server. After this, the collision map will be visible in the Planning Components Visualizer and Warehouse Viewer.

You will want to publish one of these messages:
http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/PlanningScene.html

And filling in the CollisionMap member of the message with one of these messages:
http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/CollisionMap.html

I believe that the pr2_arm_navigation_perception package has examples of how to do this.

---

Originally posted by [Matt Klingensmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/942/matt-klingensmith/) with karma: 141 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6